# How to parse parameters to a .NET application from Windows startup?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working with an app that starts at OS startup. Is there any way to know if the app was started from system startup or from a manual execution?

My current attempt (won't work):

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
     rkApp.SetValue("Low CPU Detector /fromStartup", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

then I get

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "fromStartup") {
                doSomething()
            }
(...)
```

I also read this [How to detect whether application started from startup or started by user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944571/how-to-detect-whether-application-started-from-startup-or-started-by-user) but it didn't help

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?  You should log the values from your args array so you can debug this.

Comment: Did you mean `args[0] == "/fromStartup"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
 rkApp.SetValue("Low CPU Detector", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\" /fromStartup");
```

Or in plan text -- append the parameters to the executable name in registry. The double quotes are needed to deal with possible spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The approach seems like it would mostly work, though it seems like you aren't using the registry setting correctly.  You have one big mish-mashed string value that is trying to combine what looks like the program name with the arguments that you'd pass to the program.  The system startup logic doesn't have a way to distinguish words there from command line arguments.

If it is getting passed, you're probably getting either `"Low CPU Detector /fromStartup"` as your first argument, or a set of arguments, `"Low"`, `"CPU"`, `"Detector"`, `"/fromStartup"`.  But I suspect that the command line argument isn't getting passed at all.  You will probably have to pass the arguments along with the executable name.

So, to register your application, you'll want to do something like this:

```
const string runKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
const string programName = "Low CPU Detector";
string commandToExecute = string.Format(@""{0}" /fromStartup",
    Application.ExecutablePath);

using(RegistryKey runKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(runKeyPath, true))
{
    runKey.SetValue(programName, commandToExecute);
}
```

Note that `RegistryKey` implements `IDisposable`, so put it in a using block.

Also, you have a typo in your command line parsing code. The `/` doesn't get special treatment from the shell, and is passed to your code as-is.

You should add some logging of your command line arguments so you can debug this.